# ExtJS load data to Form from Store with association

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a single form that has fields for a Employee Model and fields for Person Model.

**Employee Model**

```
Ext.define('App.model.Employee', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
            name: 'EmployeeId',
            type: 'int'
        },  
        {
            name: 'PersonId',
            type: 'int'
        },
        'EmployeeNumber',
        'JoinDate'
    ],  
    belongsTo: 'App.model.Person'
});
```

**Person Model**

```
Ext.define('App.mode.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
            name: 'PersonId',
            type: 'int'
        },  
        'FirstName',
        'LastName'
    ],
    hasMany: {
        model: 'App.model.Employee',
        name: 'Employees'
    }   
});
```

My Store:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'App.model.Employee',
    autoLoad: false,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'api/employee/getemployee'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        }
    }
});
```

This is my actual JSON

```
"data": [{
        "EmployeeId": 5,
        "PersonId": 1,
        "EmployeeNumber": 2001,
        "JoinDate" : "",
        "Person": {
            "PersonId": 1,
            "FathersLast": "SMITH",
            "FirstName": "JOHN"
        }
    }],
```

My question is how does my json response (from server) should be structured in order to load store successful?

Answer (score 0):

You can find explanation and sample code in [Ext data package guide](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/data) section "Loading Nested Data". Other example is in the heading of [Association documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association). Both with sample JSON files showing the required structure.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code and json structure i can recognize that each employee has a person object, so you  need to correct your mapping. Instead of Defining hasMany relationship in person model, you should define hasOne relationship for person in employee.

hasOne: {
        model: 'App.mode.Person',
        name: 'Person'
    }

Please try this out. Your json structure looks good.